# Custom swipe function in UITableViewCell doesn't work

Tags: swipe, tap

I need to add the count in the uitableviewcell in a such a way that when I trigger the swipe function the count should be incremented in the corresponding cell and while tapping the count should be decremented.

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"sample";
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

    recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    self.tapRecognizer = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [recognizer release];

    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];

    [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];
    UILabel *cookieLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5, 120,30)];
    cookieLabel.text = @"hello";
    cookieLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
    cookieLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cookieLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cookieLabel];
    [cookieLabel release];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

    costLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 200, 5, 230, 30)];
    //costLabel.text = handleSwipeFrom:;
    costLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
    costLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    costLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:costLabel];
    [costLabel release];
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: it will help if you format the code in your question as code... it is impossible to read this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add the UISwipeGestureRecognizer to the cell. Add it to the UITableView.

I used TISwipeableTableView as a base and modified it heavily to work correctly (they did their own touch handling, which resulted in a "weird, unnative" feeling)

```
- (void)didSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
  if ([MRUserDefaults sharedMRUserDefaults].isSwipeMenuEnabled) {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
      CGPoint swipeLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self];
      NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipeLocation];
      TISwipeableTableViewCell* swipedCell = (TISwipeableTableViewCell *)[self cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];

      if ([swipedCell isKindOfClass:[TISwipeableTableViewCell class]]) {
        if (![swipedIndexPath isEqual:indexOfVisibleBackView]) {
          [self hideVisibleBackView:YES];
          [swipedCell revealBackView];
          [self setIndexOfVisibleBackView:swipedIndexPath];  

          if (swipeDelegate && [swipeDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSwipeCellAtIndexPath:)]){
            [swipeDelegate tableView:self didSwipeCellAtIndexPath:[self indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipeLocation]];
          }        
        }
      }
    }  
  }
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style {
  if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame style:style])) {
    if ([MRUserDefaults sharedMRUserDefaults].isSwipeMenuEnabled) {
      UIGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)] autorelease];
      [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
    }
  }
  return self;
}
```

This should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

[cell addGestureRecognizer:recognizer]